# WPF not rendering bitmapImage using creation option DelayCreation

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

The following code is a converter for a url bound to an image source. The image is part of an item template for a listbox bound to an observableCollection containing the urls.

Also, this code is for windows 7 desktop, not silverlight.

The converter:

```
BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage();
myImage.BeginInit();
myImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;
myImage.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
myImage.EndInit();
return myImage;
```

The xaml:

```
Image Source="{Binding MyUrlProperty, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"
```

When I run this code, the listbox renders its content without the images. I added a breakpoint to some throwaway code in the .DownloadCompleted event and I can confirm it loads the images into the object. Furthermore, it doesn't seem to delay creation, as it seems to load every image in the list even outside current scrolled view but that is another issue.

When I remove the createOptions flag for DelayCreation, it works. All images load.

Anyone familiar with why this happens and perhaps some workaround advice? Is this possibly a bug?

Comment: `DelayCreation` doesn't mean that the image buffer is downloaded immediately. Just the displayed bitmap isn't created until actually needed. But why do you have such a converter *at all*. It is redundant, as WPF provides built-in type conversion from `string` and `Uri` to `ImageSource`.

Comment: Having said that, your converter works fine for me, at least with local file URLs.

Comment: The custom converter is used to create a bitmapImage object with the delayCreation flag set. The default image source converter used by image does not do this. Furthermore, I did say that I verified the objects do download their content immediately(even the ones outside of the viewscreen scroll of the list box). Lastly, the problem is that none of them render on screen. If I remove that one line, it works fine.

Comment: I've understood all that. My point is that you seem to be confusing delayed image creation with virtualization. Although I can't explain why the images created by your converter aren't displayed, I'd still say that you don't need it at all. What you want to have is virtualization, which is explained in the Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) and should work by default in a WPF ListBox.

Comment: Ya, I want both. The virtualization should come by default with my listBox and my observableCollection. I've found that this does not seem to be the case(watching the bitmapImage.DownloadComplete events fire way down the list without even scrolling to them). Similarly, the load of the whole list takes longer if I add more unique images so something is broken. However, this is separate issue. I only mentioned it as it pertained to my investigation into image loading yet not rendering for the DelayCreation issue I'm having. I understand they are different features.